# When running git status the following error happens after Mojave update: "xcrun: error: invalid active developer path"

Tags: xcode, git, macos-mojave, xcrun

I've tried running:

1) `xcode-select --reset`

2) `xcode-select --install`

But I still get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to go to:

`https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=for%20Xcode`

and manually download the correct xcode tools for your version of MacOS and install them!